# How to change body background-color for only IOS devices using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to detect IOS device and set a different background color. But my code is not working. How can I do this simply with pure javascript ...?

JAVASCRIPT

```js
var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if (isIOS){
  document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  console.log('This is an IOS device');
} else{
  console.log('This is Not an IOS device');
}
```

Comment: This code should work, can you tell which device are you using or maybe another div color is showing to you above body?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. This is really hard to test the change as I don't have any IOS device but I used lambdatest.com to check which was so laggy. There was no change though in body. If you have access to iphone running on safari please check https://soumy-11.github.io/elomymelo/jbl%20flip%206%20meaningful%20upgrade.html  there is an animation 300 ms which is the body. But if that code worked then there should be no animation on white background. The background should be black always.

Comment: On android, windows and in mac the starting body animation which is kinda fast looks cool. But it looks weird on iphone ios. The background size isn't right. Appears so big on iphone. Every time you reload the animation should appear for exact 292 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Only iphone detection is working but ipad detection not working. But in my case to change the background the setInterval function worked.

```js
var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if (isIOS && window.matchMedia("(max-width: 615px)").matches) {
  console.log("This is an IOS device");
  setInterval(function () {
    document.body.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  }, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I’ve used `backgroundColor` to make it more specific

```
var isIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if (isIOS) {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
  console.log('This is an iOS device');
} else {
  console.log('This is Not an iOS device');
}
```

You could set a class instead, and in the class specify

```
.my-class { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1) ! important; }
```

`! important` should make it override other styles.